# How to filter :time_zone between GMTs using simple-form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

```
= simple_form_for user,
  = f.input :time_zone
```

Return a dropbox with all timezones between GMT-11:00 to GMT+13:00 and it respective timezone names.

How to filter/show only between GMT+02:00 to GMT-05:00 at dropbox and it to keep the same structure with `(GMT-HH:MM) ZONE_NAME`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I founded was add a helper:

```
module TimezonesHelper
  def timezones_filtered
    [['(GMT-05:00) Lima',     'Lima'     ],
     ['(GMT-04:00) La Paz',   'La Paz'   ],
     ['(GMT-03:00) Brasilia', 'Brasilia' ],
     ['(GMT+00:00) UTC',      'UTC'      ]]
  end
end
```

And used this way:

```
= simple_form_for user
    = f.input :time_zone, selected: 'Brasilia', collection: timezones_filtered
```